# Entity Framework Query Results Duplicate

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, duplicate-data, multiple-resultsets

- I created a SQL View that joins a few tables and when tested in SQL
  Manager it provides the correct data (If a makes a difference these are complex joins).
- In MVC I created a (data first) Entity Data Model and then added code
  generation.
- I have a LINQ query in a controller that generates an idex page.

All basic MVC stuff.

When I run the application I receive duplicate records.  To further qualify, if an order has more than one line it returns the first record for each line in the "order".

```
SQL Results
Order, Line, Part
12345, 1, 3829138120
12345, 2, 1238401890

MVC/EF Results
Order, Line
12345, 1, 3829138120
12345, 1, 3829138120
```

Any thoughts as to the cause of this problem?

Comment: Perhaps post some scaled down code segments? In particular the LINQ query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should double check the entity key attributes. I see your query result and you should mark as primary key Order and Line and I think that you have forget mark order as key.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, danihp.

**Resolution**: To fix the problem I opened the Entity Data Model (edmx file) and select the Field _(OrderLine)_ property in the Entity Set *(SalesOrders)*. Opened the Properties for the field and set the Entity Key value to true.  (I also found many fields that were set as Entity Keys that probably shouldn't be.)

Comment: Hi Pete, a happy end ... or begin. Good luck with your project and thanks about explaning detailed resolution.