# Entity Framework query result

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I'm using EntityFramework 4.3.1 and trying to run a query like this

```
Context.Set<KullaniciYetkiView>().Where(y => y.KullaniciId == kullaniciId && y.YetkiKod == yetkiKod)
```

When i run the query and it returns 115 records as expected. But when i look the record all of them is same. So i listen the query from profiler for to look what am i missing, is see the below query and its return 115 different records from management studio.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[YetkiKod] AS [YetkiKod], 
[Extent1].[KullaniciId] AS [KullaniciId], 
[Extent1].[LokasyonId] AS [LokasyonId], 
[Extent1].[YetkiId] AS [YetkiId], 
[Extent1].[HiyerarsikKod] AS [HiyerarsikKod], 
[Extent1].[LokasyonSeviye] AS [LokasyonSeviye], 
[Extent1].[Yetkili] AS [Yetkili], 
[Extent1].[Engelli] AS [Engelli], 
[Extent1].[LokasyonEngelli] AS [LokasyonEngelli]
FROM [dbo].[sayKullaniciYetkiView] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[KullaniciId] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[YetkiKod] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 uniqueidentifier,@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0='283CCB41-3BDF-4BEF-BD26-E46191CA069D',@p__linq__1=N'FIN.SATISFATURA.E'
```

I think the problem is in EF and to prove it I run the code like this

```
        var yetkiler1 = Context.Set<KullaniciYetkiView>().Where(y => y.KullaniciId == kullaniciId && y.YetkiKod == yetkiKod).Distinct().ToList();
        var yetkiler2 = Context.Set<KullaniciYetkiView>().Where(y => y.KullaniciId == kullaniciId && y.YetkiKod == yetkiKod).ToList().Distinct();
```

First query returns 115 rows and the second returns 1.

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There seems to be something fishy with that KullaniciId column. The generated query treats it as a unique ID, yet it returns 115 records?

Comment: It may be a problem with your model config.  Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/7955773/1099260.

Comment: Yes, and it must return 115 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Quinton said my model configuration is wrong.

if you have more than 1 column as key you should set them on contexts **OnModelCreating** method like `modelBuilder.Entity<KullaniciYetkiView>().HasKey(ky => new { ky.KullaniciId, ky.LokasyonId, ky.YetkiId });`

Here is the HasKey method explanation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671266(v=vs.103).aspx